Die Festung Hamburg: Blocking units and movement
This question pertains to Fabrizio Vianello games which share similar rules, such as "Die Festung Hamburg" and "Less Than 60 Miles".  The question has also been posted here on bgg.
A unit moves adjacent to an enemy blocking unit and stops. Another unit then moves into the stopped unit's hex. Can that moving unit continue to move using case 8.6.4.c if it moves into a new hex. Or must the first hex adjacent to an enemy blocking unit be occupied by a unit that hasn't already moved in the movement phase? Otherwise this seems to create a tactic where a moving unit can stop and provide a "safe hex" allowing other units to slide past enemy blocking units.
